# How to prevent this css shape to scroll left and right

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I would like to keep this shape so it is responsive and keeps the same direction, and that it can still scroll down the page. The problem is that because of its size it scrolls left and right, which I wish to avoid.

If I set `overflow: hidden;` to its parent element (body), it causes all other content to vanish in the bottom when it reaches it.

Is there a way to prevent the page to scroll left and right, to "cut" the extra part? Thank you

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oytvt0p7/

```
  #angled-shape { 
    width: 3000px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -1000px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;

    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-30deg); /* Standard syntax */
}

<div id="angled-shape"></div>
```

Comment: From your earlier question and my comment about gradients : https://jsfiddle.net/80qLds4o/6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just set [`overflow-x: hidden;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x), so scrolling in y direction will be nevertheless possible:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#angled-shape {
  width: 3000px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: -1000px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<div id="angled-shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try bellow CSS

```
position: fixed; 
overflow-y: scroll;
top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
```